# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale' Attribute Error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Here I found an error after updating it face to img. The error says:

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
0 549 374
1 518 362
2 487 351
3 462 353
4 449 359
5 469 318
6 428 348
7 438 367
8 453 371
9 473 321
10 434 363
11 447 382
12 463 387
13 479 334
14 443 377
15 456 396
16 471 402
17 487 352
18 457 385
19 458 402
20 463 413
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maruf/Documents/python/opencv/YouTube/Hand Tracking/basic.py", line 35, in <module>
    faceDetails = img.detectMultiScale(
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my source code of this part:

```
col = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faceDetails = img.detectMultiScale(
        col,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

for (x, y, w, h) in faceDetails:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Why it says that error...
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale'

Comment: I updated it and it returns some landmarks with the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

**The cause of your error:**
`detectMultiScale` is indeed **not** a method of `numpy.ndarray`, which is apparently the type of your `img` object.

**The solution:**
`detectMultiScale` is actually a method of opencv [`CascadeClassifier`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html) class.
See the documentation here: [`detectMultiScale`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#a90fe1b7778bed4a27aa8482e1eecc116).
Your `img` should be passed as the first argument to `detectMultiScale` (there are additional optional pramaters as you can see in the documentation link).

**Note** that in order to obtain a `CascadeClassifier` object you must load the classifier data from the model file. The link above offers an example in c++. I am sure a quick search will yield you an example in python.

Comment: I updated this part now I am facing the same error with some landmarks result

Comment: You are still using `detectMultiScale` as if it was a method of `img`. Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Problem solved Thanks
I didn't import this line previous time
`face = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/maruf/Documents/python/opencv/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")`